# ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) Resource name must use only lowercase letters, numbers and '-'. ... Maximum length is 63 characters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm writing a GitHub Action to deploy my application to Cloud Run (a GCP service) with action [deploy-cloudrun](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun#metadata-customizations). It successfully create and push my application image to the artifact registry, but it failed to deploy to Cloud Run.

And I don t know what name is too long or how to change it ?

From Github Action console :

```
Running: gcloud beta run deploy xxxxxxxxxxxxx --quiet --platform managed --region xxxxxxxxxxxx --tag 1.0.0 --revision-suffix v1.0.0 --project xxxxxxxx --format json
Error: failed to execute gcloud command `gcloud beta run deploy xxxxxxxxxxxxx --quiet --platform managed --region xxxxxxxxxxxx --tag 1.0.0 --revision-suffix v1.0.0 --project xxxxxxxx --format json`: This command is equivalent to running `gcloud builds submit --tag [IMAGE] .` and `gcloud run deploy xxxxxxxxxxxxx --image [IMAGE]`

Building using Dockerfile and deploying container to Cloud Run service [xxxxxxxxxxxxx] in project [xxxxxxxx] region [xxxxxxxxxxx]
Building and deploying...
Uploading sources.........done
Building Container..................................done
failed
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) Resource name must use only lowercase letters, numbers and '-'. Must begin with a letter and cannot end with a '-'. Maximum length is 63 characters.
```

My workflow :

```yaml
name: Deploy to production

...

jobs:
  deployment-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v0
        with:
          ...
      - name: Deploy to Cloud Run
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v0
        with:
          service: ${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}
          image: ${{ env.RUN_REGION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/cloud-run-source-deploy/${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}:latest
          project_id: ${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}
          region: ${{ env.RUN_REGION }}
          tag: ${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
```

Comment: I see you are using uppercase letters and spaces in your names.Can you try deploying it by changing the name by following the convention i.e, using lowercase letters, numbers and '_'. Let me know if that works!

Comment: How did you solve the error? I got same error following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5EfITuFD9w

Answer (score 3):

According to your error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) Resource name must use only lowercase letters, numbers and '-'. Must begin with a letter and cannot end with a '-'. Maximum length is 63 characters
```

You can check what contains your env var `env.SERVICE_NAME` and make it compliance with the requirements of the error.

- Resource name must use only lowercase letters, numbers and '-'.
- Must begin with a letter and cannot end with a '-'.
- Maximum length is 63 characters

The aforementioned is defined in [this GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/ObjectMeta) which points to [This K8s reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/#dns-label-names) about RFC 1035 Label Names. This is in similar to the GCP Docs

```
..This means the name must:

contain at most 63 characters
contain only lowercase alphanumeric characters or '-'
start with an alphabetic character
end with an alphanumeric character
```